# How to remove default Quarkus-generated annotations?

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

Quarkus generates such annotations by default:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/commit-id: 88216f576f4a6f58862be6a6ef993036420e1eda
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2022-07-18 - 18:28:39 +0000
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/path: /q/metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    prometheus.io/scheme: http
```

Some annotations are useless because it makes K8s configuration very volatile and not commitable to Git (`app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp` etc). Some are simply invalid - Prometheus annotations at the Deployment level are junk.

This forces me to decline the manifest generation feature at all but it is very useful, especially for Operator development.

How to filter those auto-generated annotations or disable such generation altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, it is possible to add `quarkus.kubernetes.idempotent=true` to disable both `build-timestamp` and `commit-id` annotations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `quarkus.kubernetes.add-build-timestamp=false` will disable the `app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp` label.

See:

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-kubernetes_quarkus.kubernetes.add-build-timestamp.

For the Prometheus annotations, you can use `quarkus.kubernetes.prometheus.annotations=false`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. `app.quarkus.io/commit-id` can't be removed?

Comment: I don't know if this is useful in anyway for you but the only way I found how to remove these annotations was in the service directly: ````kubectl annotate service service-name app.quarkus.io/commit-id- ````

Comment: @SirHawrk thanks. No this will not help because I want to track configuration in Git so before it applies to the cluster. The annotation itself is not a problem - its volatility is.

Comment: @geonad Can I file an issue to disable `app.quarkus.io/commit-id` generation or annotations at all?

Comment: Go right ahead.